Azure pipeline: One or more project in the solution were not loaded properly
I have an Azure pipeline that is using MSBuild to build project. Inside build.proj file, there is a command to run devenv.com to build a vdproj file.
We have few vdproj file in the solution. Recently, there is an issue when running the pipeline, it hit the error below:

E:\BuildAgent5_work\1\s\src\XXX_Setup\XXX_Setup.vdproj : error : The
operation was canceled. [E:\BuildAgent5_work\1\s\build\Build.proj]
One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.

However, when we manually run MSBuild command in the server, there is no issue. The build agent and visual studio are already up to date.
Besides, I tried to add line below to my yaml in order to run the command directly from the pipeline and it produced the same error. There is no issue when run the command in pipeline server.
script: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "E:\BuildAgent5\_work\1\s\XXXX.sln" /Build "Release" /project "E:\BuildAgent5\_work\1\s\src\XXXX_v6.5.0_Setup\XXXX_Setup.vdproj" /projectconfig "Release"'
displayName: 'Testing'
continueOnError: false

Anyone encounter this issue before?

Please share your DevOps pipeline definition(yaml), and build.proj file for troubleshooting. In addition, please go the source code folder in the agent (E:\BuildAgent5_work\1\s), if you run the command again, will it succeed?

I tried to run directly the command using pipeline. I added below line to my yaml file: (- script: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "E:\BuildAgent5_work\1\s\XXXX.sln" /Build "Release" /project "E:\BuildAgent5_work\1\s\src\XXXX_v6.5.0_Setup\XXXX_Setup.vdproj" /projectconfig "Release"'
      displayName: 'Testing'
      continueOnError: false) and I still am getting the same error. I am able to run the command in the source code folders and in the server. Is it pipeline has limited access to devenv.com?

@Teong it's very hard to read code in comments. Please edit your answer and paste the yaml code there.

@RuiJarimba added the code in description

The same task works on my side. Can you add whoami in the pipeline task, rerun pipeline to check the user? Is it same with your local user? And did you restart the agent after the extension installed on VS? Add variable system.debug as true in pipeline to check the diagnostic debug log, please share if there are more error details.

The pipeline is using NETWORK SERVICE account which is different from local user. Even I added network service account to local admin group, the issue still persists.

Looks wired. please give a try to reconfigure the agent with same local user. When the pipeline started, check the real command executed from pipeline log, compare it with local working command.

I think it is due to the Microsoft visual studio installer project 2022 extension. It is installed and access already granted for network service account but it seems like it is not working for network service account

Thanks @Teong! On my self-hosted agent installed with nt authority\network service  account, the task is still working in pipeline.  Maybe other reason like ASC or folder permission caused the issue, but you can firstly reconfigure the agent with local user for a test, confirm if it's working. Let me know if it works.

@Teong, the nt authority\network service works fine on my side. and it could be caused by other permission on the this account, may i know if you have reconfigured the agent with same local user, and does it work now?

Since the command works on agent folder directly, the issue could be caused by the account network service which is configured as agent user.
Please reconfigure the agent with same local user, and rerun the pipeline.

@Teong, as we talked above, the network service account doesn't work as expected with the extension, please reconfigure the agent with same local user, let me know if it works, thanks.
